# Automated/smart checkouts - should there be a limit?

Tags: gui-design, e-commerce

I am currently redesigning the UX of an online checkout. I know there are possibilities to automate a fair bit of form filling for registered customers, but I get the feeling that this can be too much and act like the customer doesnt have much control of the site.

For example - THE OPTION TO COLLECT PURCHASE FROM STORE

1 - The customer details. We already got them at registration so ALREADY COMPLETED

2 - Smart recognition of previous store selected to collect a previous item so ALREADY SELECTED FROM LIST

3 - All that the customer needs to do is hit the CTA to move onto the payment page.

On a mobile page, the customer could find themselves landing on the page looking like this

[image: The page would have auto scrolled to the CTA at the bottom]

Am i right in thinking this is forceful rather than smart? Would love you know peoples thoughts on this.

Dan

Answer (score 2):

It may seem forceful to a user who wishes to enter a different information to that which is auto-populated. But for a user who wishes to submit the reoccurring information for these fields, auto-populating is a smart and friendly experience.

The best way to find a balance between the two ends of the spectrum, is to leave the fields empty on page load, but have an easy to see, easy to use, button or toggle that when selected it will auto-populate the information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes sense. Amazon pre-loads your previous delivery address, and I accidentally clicked Next or Confirm (whichever it is) and the item got sent to my old workplace, which meant I had to go a lot of trouble to get it.

Comment: At least once, I've accidentally one-clicked to the entirely wrong country, with Amazon one-click!  heh